# Modules qualified under Haskell namespace Control or Data

Tags: haskell

What properties are supposed to put Haskell `modules` under namespace rather `Control` than `Data` or vice versa? Any guidelines or insights are much appreciated.

Comment: control(structures) and data(structures)? - no really: if you say what you've got it might be easier to answer - aside from that have a look around hackage: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/#cat:Control and http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/#cat:Data - I think that should give you an intuition

Answer (score 4):

Haskell has [rough guidelines](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hierarchical_module_names)
on how to name module names. You can go through that link to get an general idea about it. The general convention is that `Control` will hold some sort of abstraction pattern where as `Data` will hold some data types and data structure.